# How to crunch data in python but add to MERN Stack Application

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, numpy, data-science, mern

I am trying to create a health score system for my company’s clients. There is a lot of data that I am pulling from through my API. I was crunching data through g-scripts but it is taking a really long time, so I thought using Numpy's vectorization would make things much faster. I was thinking of creating a new web application using the MERN stack but I would like to crunch the data using python. Any suggestions on what to do?

Answer (score 1):

A MERN stack is essentially javascript, so there's a ceiling to the amount of calculation you can realistically do on the backend with a vanilla implementation.

I would build a *native daemon* that runs your Python code, place it in a *docker container*, and choosing your favorite messaging/transportation system to communicate with your backend API. There are plenty of choices there:

- Websockets (raw)
- Messaging Queue Libraries (IE ZeroMQ)
- MongoDB change streams (Since you are using MERN)

So a classic life cycle would of a data crunch event would be:

1. Issue a rest-ful command to backend API
2. Backend API issues a message to daemon using your messaging system
3. Daemon awakes and crunches data
4. Daemon sends back result via messaging system to rest-ful api
5. Backend API reads the message back and send result to front-end

Comment: What do you mean by native daemon?

Comment: @AaronCheung I mean a process that runs a compiled/optimized version of your data crunch implementation and it's accessible to the MERN stack via those means described above (Websockets etc...).